# Need a script to edit file

Tags: php, perl, bash, cakephp

```
<?php
class DATABASE_CONFIG {
    public $default = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'hostname',
        'login' => 'username',
        'password' => 'password',
        'database' => 'database_name',
        'prefix' => '',
        //'encoding' => 'utf8',
    );
    public $test = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'hostname',
        'login' => 'username',
        'password' => 'password',
        'database' => 'database_name',
        'prefix' => '',
        //'encoding' => 'utf8',
    );
}
```

There are some default value in login,password and database. How can i write a script to edit the login,password and database ?

Comment: you want to change both $default and $test blocks or just $test?

Comment: Yes, i want to change both $default and $test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

php file contains your example text:

```
kent$  awk '/login/{l++;if(l>1)gsub(/root/,"newLogin");} 
        /password/{p++;if(p>1)gsub(/xxx/,"newPwd");} 
        /database/{d++;if(d>1)gsub(/xxx/,"newDB");} 1' php
<?php
class DATABASE_CONFIG {

    public $default = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'login' => 'root',
        'password' => 'xxx',
        'database' => 'xxx',
        'prefix' => '',
        //'encoding' => 'utf8',
    );

    public $test = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'login' => 'newLogin',
        'password' => 'newPwd',
        'database' => 'cake_test_db',
        'prefix' => '',
        //'encoding' => 'utf8',
    );
}
```

this only changes the blocks after your $default block. and, **only** default value will be changed. e.g. in your $test, `'database' => 'cake_test_db'` the value is not the default 'xxx', so it would not be changed.

if you like you can put new value in variable, and passing to awk with -v.

**edit**

if you want to change all values, (including $default block), it would be easier, check the lines below: (same as above, only defalut values (root, xxx,xxx) would be changed.

```
kent$    awk '/login/{gsub(/root/,"newLogin");}                                                                                          
            /password/{gsub(/xxx/,"newPwd");}                                                                                            
            /database/{gsub(/xxx/,"newDB");} 1' php                                                                                      
<?php
class DATABASE_CONFIG {

    public $default = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'login' => 'newLogin',
        'password' => 'newPwd',
        'database' => 'newDB',
        'prefix' => '',
        //'encoding' => 'utf8',
    );

    public $test = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'login' => 'newLogin',
        'password' => 'newPwd',
        'database' => 'cake_test_db',
        'prefix' => '',
        //'encoding' => 'utf8',
    );
}
```

**edit2**

this works for your new example in question.

```
 sed '/login/{s/username/newLOGIN/}; /password/{s/password/newPWD/2}; /database/{s/database_name/newDB/}' php

    <?php
    class DATABASE_CONFIG {
        public $default = array(
            'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
            'persistent' => false,
            'host' => 'hostname',
            'login' => 'newLOGIN',
            'password' => 'newPWD',
            'database' => 'newDB',
            'prefix' => '',
            //'encoding' => 'utf8',
        );
        public $test = array(
            'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
            'persistent' => false,
            'host' => 'hostname',
            'login' => 'newLOGIN',
            'password' => 'newPWD',
            'database' => 'newDB',
            'prefix' => '',
            //'encoding' => 'utf8',
        );
    }
```

Comment: It's only changing the $test block, not the $default .

Comment: This is the output i got with your script, http://dpaste.com/650300/ , this is the script i used => http://dpaste.com/650301/

Answer (score 1):

```
    #!/usr/bin/awk -f

    BEGIN {   FS="'"   

         usr[0] ="usr1"   ;  usr[1] = "user2" 
        pass[0] ="pass1"  ; pass[1] = "pass2" 
          db[0] ="db1"    ;   db[1] = "db2"
    }  
    {
    if ($2 == "login") { 
        $0="\t'login' => '" usr[u] "',"
        u++
    } 
    if ($2 == "password") { 
        $0="\t'password' => '" pass[p] "',"
        p++
    }
    if ($2 == "database") { 
        $0="\t'database' => '" db[d] "',"
        d++
    }
     print
    }
```